# Hiding datagrids on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to be able to select a datagrid to display to the user depending on a button i click, i have three different datagrids. So when i select button_1 i need to show datagrid_1 and then datagrid_2 and datagrid_3 need to be hidden in the user interface.

In windows forms you could simply say:

```
datagrid_1.Visible = false; / datagrid_1.Visible = true;
```

In WPF this doesn't work, so i am wondering how i would go about hiding datagrids on button click. Using datagrid_1.IsVisible does not work either.

This is how i would have normally done it in windows forms:

```
        protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            datagrid_1.Visible = true;
            datagrid_2.Visible = false;
            datagrid_3.Visible = false;
            lblPageHeader.Text = "datagrid_1 is selected";
        }
```

My only other idea was to put these datagrids in their own user controls and then load the user control based on the button click but surely there is a quicker way to achieve this? So what would be the best way to achieve similar results in WPF?

Comment: you can write `datagrid_1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`

Comment: @bars222 i have tried that but i get the error: Member 'System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

Comment: Did you created DataGrids in code behind? Can you provide code, how you creating and initializing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Visibility` property in WPF

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            datagrid_1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            datagrid_2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            datagrid_3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            lblPageHeader.Text = "datagrid_1 is selected";
        }
```

Comment: Well i had to use System.Windows.Visibility.Visible but ill mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you can use databindings, to achieve the same.

Here's a link to a short tutorial about databinding:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html

Comment: Thanks ill give it a try!

Comment: @zen_1991 Good luck! :)